# Get dom element . setAttribute("size", "50") is not working

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes

I have .settAttribute("size"'"50") set to my  document.getElementById("inputDiv") but somehow it is not working. All the other attributes are working though. This attribute is suppose to change the character size of my input.

Thanks in advance!

JS:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("value", "");
  input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Type your name then press Enter");
  input.setAttribute("maxLength", "4");
```

> input.setAttribute("size", "50");

```
  var parent = document.getElementById("inputDiv");
  parent.appendChild(input);
  parent.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  parent.style.width = '50%';
  parent.style.margin = 'auto';
  parent.style.borderWidth = '0px 0px .5px 0px';
  parent.style.color = 'black';
```

Comment: There is no recognized "size" attribute.

Comment: "*the character size of my input*". Do you mean the font-size or the maximum number of characters you can enter?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
input.setAttribute('maxlength', 50);
```

Note, if your "size" means "font-size", then the code should be:

```
input.style.setProperty('font-size', '50px');
```

Comment: I was actually looking into "size" atttribute to increase the number of characters. Somehow I got it to work.